# failed to start custom systemd service at boot

Tags: systemd

I have created docker-registry.service file as follows:

```
[Unit]
description=DockerRegistry
After=docker.service network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/docker-registry
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

however when i run the service with following:

```
service docker-registry start
```

I get:

```
docker-registry: unrecognized service
```

if I try following:

```
  systemctl start docker-registry
```

I get:

```
Failed to start docker-registry.service: Unknown unit: docker-registry.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status docker-registry.service' for details.
```

Please suggest.

**EDIT:**
I am using systemd in Virtual machine.

Comment: Where is this file? Also, what operating system are you on?

Comment: The first version of the command is wrong (e.g. you want `systemctl start whatever`). What directory did you put your `.service` file in? It's saying it can't find it.

Comment: i have placed it under /etc/systemd/system

Comment: i am using ubuntu server 16.04

Comment: when i check this systemctl status docker-registry.service i get Failed to get properties: No such interface ''

Comment: Is your file in `/etc/systemd/system` in the host operating systemd on the virtual machine? It needs to be in the virtual machine.

Comment: Is there any update even am facing same issue after reboot